# This script display none does not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms

I have a page in which the user has to check the radio button - if he is a new user he is redirected to a different page.

If he is an existing user and he checks this button then 2 boxes appear: `username` and `password`

For some reason this script does not work on chrome.

Thank you for your help

```
<script>
    function dispLoing(val)
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById ? 
                     document.getElementById("loginForm").style :
                     document.all ?
                         document.all.loginForm :
                         document.loginForm;

        if (val == "new")
        {
            document.all.login(0).checked = true;
            obj.display = "none";
        }

        if (val == "existing")
        {
            document.all.login(1).checked = true;
            obj.display = "";
        }
    }
</script>

<td>
    <span id = "loginForm" style = "position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;
                                    z-index:80; display:none;">
        <table border=0>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <font style = "font-size: 14px">Username:</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type = "text" name = "username" 
                          style = "width: 100px; height:17px; font-size: 12px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <font style = "font-size: 14px">Password:</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type = "password" name = "pass"
                          style = "width: 100px; height: 17px; font-size: 12px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
```

Comment: Why don't you use jquery , it will be much easier then .

Comment: Why are you going anywhere near `document.all`? Is support for Internet Explorer 4 a requirement?

Comment: Where is `dispLoing()` called?

Comment: This doesn't look like all your code. Commented out the missing bits. Works in Chrome for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/qLpe9/ (Also replaced the `span` with `div`, though either way doesn't matter).

Comment: it was before div and i have changed it to span.

Comment: in your script you do not have the rest of my style script and maybe this is why it worked for you - here is the script  <span id="loginForm" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:80;display:none;">

Answer (score 3):

`document.all` is proprietary Microsoft junk, useful only if you need to support IE 4. These days it is safe to assume that `document.getElementById` is supported.

When you assign `obj`, you test to see if it exists before trying to use it.

In your two `if` statements, you use it blindly. This causes the script to die before it reaches the `obj.display` line.

```
function dispLoing(val) {
    var frm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
    var radios = frm.elements.login;
    if (val === "new") {
        radios[0].checked = true;
        frm.style.display = "none";
    } else if (val === "existing") {
        radios[1].checked = true;
        frm.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: now i do not succeed displaying the user name and pw of the existing member also on internet explorer.